# Probability/counting problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In an experiment E, nine people are asked their birth MONTH, and the nine responses are then written down. All outcomes are equally likely.

Find the probability of the event B = {NO TWO people are born in the same month.}

I know the sample space is 12^9. But i cant figure out how to get the size of B.

I know it is (12)sub9 or 12!/3! because i have the answer key. But I can't figure out why. The answer key doesn't explain. Why is the answer not just 12 choose 9? I feel the answer is 12 choose 9 because you are picking 1 month for each person, without replacement to deal with the restriction, and there are 9 people.

Comment: 12!/3! is huge. I'm pretty sure that can't be the solution.

Comment: That isn't the probability, it's the size of B according to the answer key.

Comment: If the sample space is $12^9$, that means you're treating the nine responses as distinguishable (e.g., maybe everyone writes their name as well).  So "January and eight Februaries" is a different outcome than "four Februaries, a January, and four more Februaries".  In that case, the number of outcomes where no two people share a month should be ${{12}\choose{9}}$ (choose the months) times $9!$ (choose the order), or $12! / 3!$.

Comment: Now that makes perfect sense! I didn't think about the ordering. Thank you!

Comment: Another way of counting it: How many ways are there to choose a month for the first person? 12. For the second? 11. For the third? 10. And so on... $12 \times 11 \times 10 \times \cdots \times 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this problem is to think sequentially.  What's the probability of having all different birthmonths with just 1 person?  1 (duh).  What if we add another person?  What's the probability that this new person has a different birthmonth from everybody else? 11/12.  If we keep going we see the answer is:

$$ \frac{12}{12} \times\frac{11}{12} \times \ldots \times \frac{4}{12} \approx .015 $$